# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: modules

Tags: reactjs, react-native, highcharts, es6-modules, react-highcharts

I am trying to implement highcharts wrapper within react-native application following this

https://www.highcharts.com/blog/post/creating-mobile-charts-with-highcharts-react-native/

On running the app with expo start on device, it returned me below error

> Warning: %s: Error boundaries should implement
>   getDerivedStateFromError(). In that method, return a state update to
>   display an error message or fallback UI., RootErrorBoundary
>        ReferenceError: Can't find variable: modules
>       * App.js:21:8 in render

Line 21 of App.js have the highcharts container HighchartsReactNative

Any leads will be highly helpful

Answer (score 0):

You should declare modules as array.

```
const modules = [
    'highcharts-more',
    'solid-gauge'
];
```

You can find more info in our docs (Readme.md) here:
- https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react-native

Comment: Thanks for the response Sebastian.                          My render method does not have modules and               I noticed the                                                   
 error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `@highcharts/HighchartsReactNative` from `...`: Module `@highcharts/HighchartsReactNative` does not exist in the Haste module map                                       So I changed the import to                                                                 import HighchartsReactNative from '@highcharts/highcharts-react-native';

Comment: Now on Android emulator I see html page with <div id ="container"></div>

Comment: Im working on solution with this problem still. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react-native/issues/4#issuecomment-536165094

Comment: Thanks for the update hope you find the solution early.

Comment: Please stay on track with github thread. There are a beta version of new wrapper. Lets keep all feedback there, it will allow me to prepare a better solution ;)